# Optical properties of non-Newtonian fluids

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, condensed-matter, non-linear-optics, non-newtonian-fluids

I'm interested in understanding the distinctions between non-Newtonian fluids and regular Newtonian fluids regarding their optical properties, including refractive index, nonlinear optical behavior (such as the presence of $χ₃$), birefringence, and more. While results can vary case by case, are there any general rules, such as non-Newtonian fluids being mostly, e.g., optically nonlinear?

Comment: In general non-Newtonian fluids is these which does not follow linear shear stress response or in other works for them ratio of shear stress vs shear rate is not constant. As about overall lookup on non-Newtonian fluids you can check [Non-Newtonian fluid types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Newtonian_fluid#Summary) in wiki.

Comment: Thanks! I'm primarily interested in any differences in optical properties.